# PHP/Swoole Http Server - how can I dynamically load ssl?

Tags: php, ssl, swoole

I need load different ssl certificates on the fly, on process request.  I try do it like in code below, but server still loading cert1 certificate on handling request, not cert2 as I trying to do in code.

How can I dynamically reload different certificates on the fly? Is it possible?

Code example:

```js
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$server = new swoole_http_server("192.168.10.10", 443, SWOOLE_BASE, SWOOLE_SOCK_TCP | SWOOLE_SSL);

// setup the location of ssl cert files and key files
$ssl_dir = __DIR__.'/ssl_certs';
$server->set([
    'max_conn'           => 500,
    'daemonize'          => false,
    'dispatch_mode'      => 2,
    'buffer_output_size' => 2 * 1024 * 1024,
    'ssl_cert_file' => $ssl_dir . '/cert1.local.crt',
    'ssl_key_file' => $ssl_dir . '/cert1.local.key',
    'open_http2_protocol' => true, // Enable HTTP2 protocol
]);

$server->on('request', function ($request, $response) use ($server) {
    $server->set([
        'ssl_cert_file' => $ssl_dir . '/cert2.local.crt',
        'ssl_key_file' => $ssl_dir . '/cert2.local.key',
    ]);
    $response->end("<h1>Hello World. #".rand(1000, 9999)."</h1>");
});

$server->start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't change $server configuration on the fly.

An option is to run Swoole server on multiple ports with different settings:

```
$port1 = $server->listen("127.0.0.1", 9501, SWOOLE_SOCK_TCP | SWOOLE_SSL);
$port2 = $server->listen("127.0.0.1", 9502, SWOOLE_SOCK_TCP | SWOOLE_SSL);

$port1->set([
    'open_eof_split' => true,
    'package_eof' => "\r\n",
    'ssl_cert_file' => 'ssl1.cert',
    'ssl_key_file' => 'ssl1.key',
]);

$port2->set([
    'open_eof_split' => true,
    'package_eof' => "\r\n",
    'ssl_cert_file' => 'ssl2.cert',
    'ssl_key_file' => 'ssl2.key',
]);
```

After that you can create different rules for different URIs in Nginx to handle the traffic and redirect it to the properly Swoole port.

Comment: I have a question, ssl.cert is the same to fullchain.pem and ssl.key the same to privkey.pem both generated by Let's Encrypt certbot? I'm completely stuck trying to configure SSL for Swoole with Let's Encrypt.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just need multiple certificates to provide SSL for different domain names?

If that is the case, you could just host multiple domains in a single certificate.  That would remove the requirement to switch certificates.